# The schema version of "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" is incompatible with version of NuGet

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I received this error when I build my asp.net mvc project in Visual Studio 2015:

> The schema version of 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc' is incompatible with version 2.5.40412.9018 of NuGet. Please upgrade NuGet to the latest version from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=213942.

But when I try to upgrade my NuGet, it always fails. I have uninstalled the old version "NuGet for Visual Studio 2015", and reinstalled NuGet, but I still receive the same error.

Comment: @rogerdeuce , thanks for your suggestion. Finally, I upgrade my nuget to version 3.x by command **.\nuget update -self** under the _solutiondir\packages\nugetpack.x\tools_ directory.